# Join same table to get other value in symfony 6

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder, symfony6

someone know how to join same table in symfony 6 doctrine to get different results?

I tried something like that

```
public function findAllStats(){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('count(a.id) as count, a.countryCode, count(acc) as all_accounts, count(ao) as all_online_today')
        ->leftJoin('a.accounts', 'acc', 'with', "acc.owner = a.id")
        ->andWhere('a.countryCode is not null')
        ->groupBy('a.countryCode')
        ->orderBy('count(a.id)', 'ASC')
        ->having('count(a.id) > 2')
        ->setParameter('today' , (new \DateTime())->setTime(0,0,0))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getScalarResult();

}
```

i just want to get next results and its okay:
country_code,
count of all users,
count of all accounts (relation)

but i dont know how to add:
count of all users updated today

i tried this:

```
public function findAllStats(){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('count(a.id) as count, a.countryCode, count(acc) as all_accounts, count(ao) as all_online_today')
        ->leftJoin('a.accounts', 'acc', 'with', "acc.owner = a.id")
        ->andWhere('a.countryCode is not null')
        ->groupBy('a.countryCode')
        ->orderBy('count(a.id)', 'ASC')
        ->having('count(a.id) > 2')
        ->setParameter('today' , (new \DateTime())->setTime(0,0,0))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getScalarResult();

}
```

but it doesn't works. Some solutions to join same table with different Where criteria?

but it doesn't works. Some solutions to join same table with different Where criteria?

Comment: My guess would be `SUM(a.updatedAt >= :today) as all_online_today`, but I don't really get your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found the solution. I used Class of entity and left join but is that a correct way?

```
->leftJoin(User::Class, 'ao', 'with', "ao.id = a.id AND ao.updatedAt >= :today")
```